# "Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application .. Failed to load c++ bson extension" when installing project

Tags: node.js

I get the following error:

> Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. E:\Deers\Apt3\reh-e06f34a\node_modules\mongoose\ node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\bson\build\Release\bson.node] js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version

Comment: Please have a look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and format your question better. You'll need to add some code if you want help debugging as well - though this looks more like you haven't installed Node correctly, or you're not running it correctly.

Comment: ok and thanks @remus

Answer (score 1):

seems like you used a wrong package. 
just install this one, it will work like a charm:

32bit version: 
https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.7/node-v0.12.7-x86.msi

Comment: hi could you please tell me is this support windows 7 32 bit os .

Comment: because I am using windows 32 bit os I am trying to install this package .It showed like **This installation Package is not Supported by this Processor type .contact your product vendor.**